# Looping a query from parse.com

Tags: html, parse-platform

I am using the following function to retrieve data from parse and append it to a google.maps.LatLng

For some reason, the loop does not work, if testObject contains more than one data. I think it looks exactly as many other descriptions, and I can't see why it should not work.

```
function getPoints() {
    a = [];

    var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Gas");
    var query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);

    query.find({
      success: function(testObject) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++) {
          a.push(new google.maps.LatLng(testObject[i].get("LAT"), testObject[i].get("LNG")));
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
    return a;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the asynchronous nature of the `find` Parse function. When you call this function, it will return immediately with a Parse `Promise` BUT you need to wait for the `success` callback to be called in order to get your data. Instead you are immediately returning from your `getPoints` function and it should not be a surprise that you get no results. Generally you write a function to return a Promise and wait for it to be resolved and then process the results, something like this:

```
function getPoints() {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Gas");
    return query.find();

}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
getPoints().then( function(testObject) {

    for (var i = 0; i < testObject.length; i++) {
        // process your results here
    }

}, function(error) {
   // error
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It did help make the function absolutely reliable. What I found with the previous method, is that it might return one data with database_A, but not database_B. I found it weird that database_B never returned anything. 

The major problem, was that database_B was not set to "public read/write". If data has this turned on, it worked flawless with your function and public read. Thanks!